# Swift 4: 'init' is deprecated. CountableRange is now Range

Tags: swift

I have this `String` category:

```
extension String {

    subscript (i: Int) -> String {
        return self[Range(i ..< i + 1)]
    }

    subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
        let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: max(0, min(count, r.lowerBound)),
                                            upper: min(count, max(0, r.upperBound))))
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
        let end = index(start, offsetBy: range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)
        return String(self[start ..< end])
    }
}
```

and Xcode is giving me a warning at this line:
`return self[Range(i ..< i + 1)]`

> 'init' is deprecated: CountableRange is now Range. No need to convert any more.

It's a shame that even though I'm quite well experienced with Swift, I have no idea how to fix this. Question is: how to get rid of this warning.

Thank you!

Comment: @MartinR - That doesn't seem to be a duplicate. It's a different error and a different code change. Am I missing something?

Comment: It looked like the same problem to me (CountableRange is not a separate type anymore, and the conversion method has been removed), and the same solution: Replacing `Range(i ..< i + 1)` by `i..<i+1`

Comment: @MartinR OK, after another look, I see the code change is the same. But given the error messages are so different, this is still a good question even if the solution ends of being the same as the other one.

Comment: @rmaddy: Please feel free to reopen the thread if you find it appropriate. (A reference to the other Q&A might still be useful because it explains where the problem comes from.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need the `Range.init`. In other words, change:

```
return self[Range(i ..< i + 1)]
```

to:

```
return self[i ..< i + 1]
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. Before I saw your answer, I was reading this (https://useyourloaf.com/blog/updating-strings-for-swift-4/), and tried that code above, and it worked. Will mark this as an answer in 10 mins.